# Matlab lsqnonlin() exitflag=4

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I am optimizing some test data using lsqnonlin (i.e. data simulated from known parameter values).

```
maturity=[1 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 30 36 48 60 72 84 96 108 120]'; %maturities 

options=optimset('Algorithm',{'levenberg-marquardt',.01},'Display','iter','TolFun',10^(-20),'TolX',10^-3,'MaxFunEvals',10000,'MaxIter',10000); %LM

vp0=[0.99 0.94 0.84 0.0802 -0.0144 -0.0042 0.001693 0.004094 0.003256 log(0.000960765^2) 0.077]'; %LM


[vpML,resnorm,residual,exitflag,output,lambda,jacobian]=lsqnonlin(@(vp) DNS_LL_LM(vp,y,maturity),vp0,[],[],options); %LM
```

I want the convergence to occur when the norm of the parameter vector changes by 10^-6.

As 'TolX' refers to the raw changes in the parameter vector I use 10^-3 as the tolerance of X which when squared would gives the desired norm of 10^-6.

However I find that when I run the code the exitflag keeps coming up as exitflag=4: "Magnitude of search direction was smaller than the **specified tolerance**."

But there is nowhere to set the tolerance for the search direction?

In the options you can only set: "TolX" and "TolFun"?

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html#f265106

So how can I force the optimization to keep running till my desired convergence criterion?

Kind Regards

Baz

Answer (score 1):

OK I went into the code and there seems to be some disconnect between what the exitflags as described here:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html#f265106

For example exitflag 2 which in the link above is supposed to relate to the change in x being less than tolerance is in fact used here to indicate that the Jacobian is undefined

```
if undefJac
EXITFLAG = 2;
msgFlag = 26;
msgData = {'levenbergMarquardt',msgFlag,verbosity > 0,detailedExitMsg,caller, ...
    [], [], []};
done = true;
```

The description of exitflag 4 on the mathworks page is a little vague but you can see what it is doing below:

```
if norm(step) < tolX*(sqrtEps + norm(XOUT))
    EXITFLAG = 4;        
    msgData = {'levenbergMarquardt',EXITFLAG,verbosity > 0,detailedExitMsg,caller, ...
        norm(step)/(sqrtEps+norm(XOUT)),optionFeedback.TolX,tolX};
    done = true;
```

Seems that it it testing if the norm of the stepsize is less than the tolerance of X times the norm of X. This is along the lines of what I want, and can easily be changed to give me exactly what I want.